# PhoneGap 3.3.0 WP8 project giving MSBuild error

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, windows-phone-8, msbuild

I've decided to try PhoneGap and installed the Node package for it. (Phonegap 3.3.0)

Android projects work fine. But when I try to build a WP8 (or WP7) App I get this error:

> An error occurred while building the wp7 project.ERROR: MSBuild failed
>   to create .xap when building cordova-wp7 for debugging.

I'm running Windows 8 Pro 64 bit, Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, NodeJS & PhoneGap 3.3.0

A sidenote: WP8 Projects created with the Cordova Project Templates work perfectly fine.
It's the command line version that's giving me trouble.

Comment: After installing plugin and adding reference I got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue...

Perhaps it's an issue of the required files (for compilation) not being at the said path, since I could resolve it by running in the Visual Studio Command Prompt & compile successfully:

[image]